# Sequence $sin(\alpha * n)$ limit problem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need help about this problem. I tried to solve($\alpha$=0) but I have no idea how to check for every $\alpha$.

> **Problem**:
>   Find for which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$  this sequence has a limit.
>   $$a_n=sin(\alpha *n)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $\alpha=0$ works, we now assume $\alpha\neq 0$.

If $f$ is a periodic function with irrational period then $x_n=f(n)$ does not converge.

Notice the period of $f(x)=\sin(\alpha x)$ is $\frac{2 \pi}{\alpha}$. So we need $\alpha=\frac{a}{\pi}$ with $a\in\mathbb Q$.

Now notice that if $f(x)=\sin(\frac{a}{\pi}x)$ then $f(n)$ is going to be periodic. A periodic sequence converges if and only if it is constant.

So we need $\sin(\alpha n)$ to be constant. Notice $f(0)=0$. So we require $\sin(\alpha n)=0$ for all $n$, which is possible if and only if $\alpha$ is a multiple of $\pi$.

Conclusion: $\alpha=k\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 0):

Sketch: Suppose $0<\alpha < \pi.$ Let $A = \{e^{it}: (\pi-\alpha)/4< t < 3\pi/4 + \alpha\}.$ Then the arc $A$ lies strictly above the $x$-axis and has arc length $(\pi+\alpha)/2 > \alpha.$ It follows that $e^{i\alpha n}$ lies in $A$ for infinitely many $n.$ This implies $\sin (\alpha n) > \sin [(\pi-\alpha)/4]$ for  infinitely many $n.$ Similarly, considering the arc $-A,$ we see $\sin (\alpha n) < -\sin [(\pi-\alpha)/4]$ for infinitely many $n.$ The sequence $\sin (\alpha n)$ therefore diverges.